# how to solve the $xy''+(3+x)y'+xy=0$ using power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, frobenius-method

I want to solve the above ODE just using power series centered at $x_0=-3$(not using the Frobenius method).I give some answers below, but the recursion formula looks strange, because
there are three coefficients. I don't know how to proceed.
Your help would be highly appreciated!

$$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}(x+3)^{n}$$
$$y'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}n(x+3)^{n-1}$$
$$y''=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n}n(n-1)(x+3)^{n-2}$$
$$\sum_{k=2}a_{n}n(n-1)(x+3)^{n-2}+\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=1}a_{n}n(x+3)^{n}+\sum_{n=0}a_{n}(x+3)^{n}=0$$
Compare the coefficient,
$$a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)x^{n}+a_{n+1}(n+1)x^{n}+a_{n}x^{n}=0$$
$$\implies a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)+a_{n+1}(n+1)+a_{n}=0$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I have fixed MathJax, according to what you wrote. If you agree, you can delete the image.

Comment: $$\implies(n+2)!\,a_{n+2}+(n+1)!\,a_{n+1}+n!\,a_n=0.$$

Comment: You switched the equation along the way to $y''+y'+y=0$, which is not the one you are given. You could write $(x+3)(y''+y'+y)=3(y''+y)$.

Answer (score 1):

We have this recursion:
$$
(n+2)!a_{n+2}+(n+1)!a_{n+1}+n!a_{n}=0
$$

Take $b_n=n!a_n$. Then we get $b_{n+2}+b_{n+1}+b_n=0$.

You can use the characteristic equation:
$$
x^2+x+1=0
$$
Solve $x_1=\frac{1}{2}(-1+i\sqrt{3})$ and $x_2=\frac{1}{2}(-1-i\sqrt{3})$.

So
$$
b_n=Ax_1^{n-2}+Bx_2^{n-2}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I can not understand what is the relationship between the characteristic equation and bn? Maybe I miss something important and I only know I need to write characteristic equation when solve ODE with ordinary coefficient. Thank you

Comment: It means that for $x\to\infty$ the solution behaves like $e^{-x}(c_1\cos(\sqrt3 x)+c_2\sin(\sqrt3 x))$. This in turn suggests to consider $z=xy$ to get a more symmetric, at least in some way, form of the equation that has perhaps easier coefficient recursions.